# OWL reasoner does not work for "min" cardinalities (but works for "some")

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, reasoner, hermit

I am creating a simple ontology in Protege, there is a problem with reasoning over cardinalities. Below is the toy model of the ontology. There are three instances of `A`, `B`, and `C`, that each one has 1, 2 and 3 `hasOwner` property, respectively. There are three `:Onwer` instances of `X`,`Y`, and `Z` as well.

There are two classes defined with `owl:equivalentClass`, one is `:Project` with `owl:someValuesFrom :Owner`, the other is `:JV` one with `owl:minQualifiedCardinality "2" ; owl:onClass :Owner`.

Now the reasoner correctly classifies `:JV` as a subclass of `:Project`; and it infers all three instances of `A`, `B` and `C` as instances of `:Project`, but none as `:JV`. Whereas technically, the reasoner should put all three as instances as `:Project`, and `B` and `C` as instances of `:JV` ( as they have 2, and 3 asserted `:hasOwner` properties.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing perhaps? It does not seem to be an Open World Assumption issue as well, as we are dealing with Minimum cardinalities.

```
:Owner rdf:type owl:Class .
:hasOwner rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
:Project rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                          owl:onProperty :hasOwner ;
                          owl:someValuesFrom :Owner
                        ] .
:JV rdf:type owl:Class ;
     owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty :hasOwner ;
                           owl:minQualifiedCardinality "2"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                           owl:onClass :Owner
                         ] .
:A rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
   :hasOwner :X .
:B rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
   :hasOwner :X ,
             :Y .
:C rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
   :hasOwner :X ,
             :Y ,
             :Z .
:X rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Owner .
:Y rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Owner .
:Z rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Owner .
```

Comment: in OWL there is 1) the *Open World Assumption* and 2) **no** *Unique Names Assumption* - in your case 2) is the issue - the solution is to make all individuals pairwise distinct. iirc, in Protege there is a tool for it. Otherwise, you have to add an `owl:AllDifferent` construct with a list of the individuals. In your example, at least `(:X :Y :Z)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKSW ! this solved the problem.

Comment: Hey @AKSW, while we are at this, if I wanted to put an `owl:maxQualifiedCardinality` it does not work even with the `owl:AllDifferent`. that seems to be the result of open world assumption, but is there a way to close the world on max? perhaps by asserting there is no more owners, than the distinct ones existed? (much appreciated)

Comment: yes, in that case, the Open World Assumption (OWA) is the "problem". Well, closing the world isn't that simple. There are some weird modeling approaches, mostly using some closed classes (owl:oneOf) in combination with some other constructs

Comment: These comments should be joined and make up an answer, @AKSW